# Is there a way to interact with a WebDav server in IIS from ASP.NET Core web application on the same IIS instance?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, webdav

I have a web application that is basically a document management software. The users are primarily editing files from word so I host these files in a WebDav folder in IIS to allow editing and saving from word. To access these files they use the interface built into the web application and the links showed in the browser just reference the virtual directory used for the web dav folder. This works great however when a user saves a file I would like to capture when their saving it to the SQL database the web application uses. So is there anyway for my web application to know when a user saves a file to WebDav? I may also try to utilize other code as well if I am able to allow the webdav and asp.net core web application to interact. I have scoured the internet and I could not find anything useful and I could not find anything in stackoverflow even related.

Comment: In general, saving files via WebDAV are in fact special HTTP PUT requests to IIS. So you can write your own IIS module to detect them. Then from within that module, your ASP.NET Core web app can be called to perform certain business logic.

Comment: Any simple examples you could show as an answer? I have never made an IIS module so I will have to research this.

Comment: A search engine should lead you to articles like https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-a-module-using-net

Comment: You can also refer to this Microsoft official tutorial,  hope it will help you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/develop/extending-the-management-ui/how-to-create-a-simple-iis-manager-module